# How to set Drop Down menu on mouse hover in TopMenu. Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, topmenu, drop-downs

How to set custom item in **TopMenu** to show **DropDown** menu on **mouse hover** I tried this code
`app/code/StackExchange/Menu/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="stackexchange-menu" type="StackExchange\Menu\Plugin\Menu" /> <!-- declare your own plugin -->
    </type>
</config>
```

and in the Plugin code
`app/code/StackExchange/Menu/Plugin/Menu.php`

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\Menu\Plugin;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;

class Menu
{
    /**
     * @var NodeFactory
     */
    protected $nodeFactory;

    public function __construct(
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory
    ) {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
    }

    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {
        $menu = $subject->getMenu();
        //here is how you can create a menu item.  
        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
                [
                    'data' => [
                    'name' => __('Brands'),
                    'id' => 'some-unique-id-here',
                    'url' => 'http://www.example.com/',
                    'has_active' => false,
                    'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
                ],
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $menu->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $menu->addChild($node); 

        //do the above as many times as you need.  
        //if you want to add a sumbmenu item to a menu item, create a node called `$subNode` in the same way as above and instead of calling $menu->addChild($node); call $node->addChild($subNode);  where $node is the parnet node
    }
}
```

now its works perfectly but the issue is that is shows like [image]

Now the issue is I want whenever I mouse hover on the **Brands** it shows me a **dropdown** and on dropdown shows a custom **div**. How can I set this?

Comment: So Sir how can I set this with the above *Plugin*?